# insert using pandas to_sql() missing data into clickhouse db

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, clickhouse

It's my first time using sqlalchemy and pandas to insert some data into a clickhouse db.

When I try to insert some data using clickhouse cli it works fine, but when I tried to do the same thing using sqlalchemy I don't know why one row is missing.

Have I done something wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
# created the dataframe

engine = create_engine(uri)
session = make_session(engine)
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
metadata.reflect(bind = engine)
conn = engine.connect()
df.to_sql('test', conn, if_exists = 'append', index = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this way:

```py
import pandas as pd
from infi.clickhouse_orm.engines import Memory
from infi.clickhouse_orm.fields import UInt16Field, StringField
from infi.clickhouse_orm.models import Model
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


# define the ClickHouse table schema
class Test_Humans(Model):
    year = UInt16Field()
    first_name = StringField()
    engine = Memory()


engine = create_engine('clickhouse://default:@localhost/test')

# create table
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.connection.create_table(Test_Humans) # https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.clickhouse_orm/blob/master/src/infi/clickhouse_orm/database.py#L142

pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    {'year': 1994, 'first_name': 'Vova'},
    {'year': 1995, 'first_name': 'Anja'},
    {'year': 1996, 'first_name': 'Vasja'},
    {'year': 1997, 'first_name': 'Petja'},
    # ! sqlalchemy-clickhouse ignores the last item so add fake one
    {}
])

pdf.to_sql('test_humans', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Take into account that *sqlalchemy-clickhouse* ignores the last item so add fake one (see [source code](https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse/blob/v0.1.5/connector.py#L238) and related [issue 10](https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse/issues/10)).