# Sqlalchemy shows "Code 516 Authentication failed" when trying to connect to clickhouse db

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, clickhouse

I have connected to a clickhouse db with dbeaver and installed sqlalchemy v1.3.13 and clickhouse-sqlalchemy 0.1.3 for python 3.7.

When I tried to connect with

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
engine_clickhouse = create_engine('clickhouse://use:pass@host:port/db')
engine_clickhouse.raw_connection()
```

I got

> Exception: Code: 516, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: default: Authentication failed: password is incorrect or there is no user with such name (version 20.3.4.10 (official build))

Does anybody know why?
I didn't find a similar issue.

Comment: try to check the file */etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml* on the server where ClickHouse installed - this file contains the description of all available credentials

Comment: Hi vladimir thanks! I'm pretty sure my credentials is correctly, I can use it to connect to this db with dbeaver

Comment: Hi, did you get this solved? Same problem here, I could log with the clickhouse-client command with password flag, but can not use it with python

Comment: @mingchau No I didn’t. Problem could be sqlalchemy or others, it works with clickhouse_driver try this package instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is well-known - look at [sqlalchemy-clickhouse Issue-45](https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse/pull/45) or [sqlalchemy-clickhouse Issue-49](https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse/issues/49).

To fix it need to explicitly downgrade the package *infi.clickhouse_orm* up to version *1.0.4*:

*requirements.txt*

```py
...
infi.clickhouse_orm==1.0.4
```

It allows using the [_build_params](https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.clickhouse_orm/blob/v1.0.4/src/infi/clickhouse_orm/database.py#L334)-function with the behavior expected by *sqlalchemy-clickhouse* (following versions of *infi.clickhouse_orm* aren't passed the password that leads to 'Authentication failed..'-error).

Or alternatively can be used the fork where fixed this error, for example [adaiboy fork](https://github.com/adaiboy/sqlalchemy-clickhouse).

---

I would avoid using the official [sqlalchemy-clickhouse](https://github.com/cloudflare/sqlalchemy-clickhouse) because:

- fixes not committed to master ("Latest commit was on 23 Jan 2019" !!)
- new featured not adding
- there are some issues with [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53926894/303298) etc

[clickhouse-driver](https://github.com/mymarilyn/clickhouse-driver) is the greatest alternative for *sqlalchemy-clickhouse*.

Answer (score 4):

According to @vladimir reply.I tried

```
pip uninstall infi.clickhouse_orm
pip install infi.clickhouse_orm==1.0.4
```

It worked for me.
Thanks